# Rewrite rules not working - directory list returned instead of redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, xampp

Please bear with me as I'm new to mod_rewrite. I'm trying to set up a rule such that eg domain.com/subfolder will redirect to domain.com/subfolder/subfolderindex.php, and domain.com/subfolder/subcategory will redirect to domain.com/subfolder/subcategory.php. I am testing in XAMPP. I have the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ $1/$1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ $1/$2.php
```

Instead of the redirect, I get the subfolder directory listing. When testing on the inbuilt server on a Mac, the rewrite rules work perfectly fine. Perhaps the reason for the difference is something in httpd.conf? The loadmodule line is uncommented and each AllowOverride set to All.

Here's the httpd.conf:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess


ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"


Listen 80


LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
#LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule example_module modules/mod_example.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>


ServerName localhost:80


DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>


<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>


<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>


ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

#ScriptLog "logs/cgi.log"


LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O"     combinedio
    </IfModule>


    #CustomLog "logs/access.log" common


    CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
#
# Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
# exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
# will make a new request for the document at its new location.
# Example:
# Redirect permanent /foo http://localhost/bar

#
# Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
# access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
# Example:
# Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
#
# If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
# require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
# need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
# the filesystem path.

#
# ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
# ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
# documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
# run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
# client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
# directives as to Alias.
#
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
#
# ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
# socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
#
#Scriptsock "logs/cgi.sock"
</IfModule>

#
# "C:/xampp/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig "conf/mime.types"
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp
    #AddHandler type-map var
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
</IfModule>


#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile off


# XAMPP specific settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

# Perl settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-perl.conf"

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
Include "conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf"

# Multi-language error messages
Include "conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf"

# Fancy directory listings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf"

# Language settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf"

# User home directories
Include "conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf"

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
Include "conf/extra/httpd-info.conf"

# Virtual hosts
Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
# Attention! WEB_DAV is a security risk without a new userspecific configuration for a        secure authentifcation 
# Include "conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf"

Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"

Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"

Include "conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf"

<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl.scache(512000)"
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
</IfModule>

# AJP13 Proxy
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you give an example other than subfolder/subfolderindex & subfolder/subcategory?

Comment: e.g. domain.com/services -> domain.com/services/services.php & domain.com/services/printing.php

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/?)$ /$1/$1.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)(/?)$ /$1/$2.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

These rules will give the following results:

```
http://www.domain.tld/services => http://www.domain.com/services/services.php
http://www.domain.tld/services/ => http://www.domain.com/services/services.php

http://www.domain.tld/services/printing => http://www.domain.com/services/printing.php
http://www.domain.tld/services/printing/ => http://www.domain.com/services/printing.php
```

Comment: thanks, this doesn't change anything though - I'm still getting the directory listing.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enable? I tried with my server and it worked, can you provide code sample or what you are doing with your php file?

Comment: as you can see from httpd.conf, mod_rewrite should be enabled. The php file being linked to has nothing that would interfere with anything else. It works on my Mac as well, just can't figure out why it won't on my Windows server (tried in both Xampp and QuickPHP with the same results).

Comment: I unfortunately, don't use windows so I am gonna guess here. Try disabling the auto index: #Include "conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf"